# event namespace not working in "mouseup" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to achieve `event.namespace` on a `mouseup` `event` but it doesn't seem to work, it always logs `undefined`

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
$(document).on("mouseup", function(event) {
  console.log(event)
  banner.hasClass("alt") ? banner.removeClass("alt") : banner.addClass("alt")
})


$(document).on("mouseup.namespace", function(event) {
  console.log(event.namespace)
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle of what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/221833/ Any idea?

Comment: It's because no event is triggered with a namespace. The only event triggered is a plain `mouseup`

Comment: Also note that you can justt do `banner.toggleClass('alt')` instead of the ternary

Comment: what would be the purpose to want to know that namespace inside where it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

you need to trigger `mouseup.namespace`
example here https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

also, change your namespace name from `mouseup.namespace` as it will trigger the event twice

```js
// find elements
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
$(document).on("mouseup", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  banner.toggleClass("alt");
  $(this).trigger("mouseup.namespace");
})


$(document).on("mouseup.namespace", function(event) {
  console.log(event.namespace);
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button>Change color</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this will fire the `on("mouseup.namespace")` handler twice

Comment: yes you're right, I didn't make any changes in the code, so I provided the link with an example

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in a wrong way. Try this.

```
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

$(document).on("namespace.someNamespace", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(event.namespace);
  banner.hasClass("alt") ? banner.removeClass("alt") : banner.addClass("alt")
});

$(document).on("mouseup", function(event) {
  $(document).trigger('namespace.someNamespace');
});
```

You need a normal event (e.g. `mouseup`) to trigger the namespace event.

Answer (score 0):

event.namespace is used by jQuery plugins to organize custom events

[event.namespace | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/)

> This will likely be used primarily by plugin authors who wish to handle tasks differently depending on the event namespace used.

Whatever you are trying to do, it seems like a namespace isn't the tool you're looking for.